# How to get value of node in XML with namespace and not throw exception if node is not found?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I'm using LinqToXml to get the value of notes with the name `GUID`. So XML can look like this:

```
<xml>
   <node1>
      <GUID>123948390</GUID>
   </node1>
<xml>
```

It may also be nested into more nodes. There is only one GUID per possible XML string.

What I am trying to do is parse the XML to collect the GUID element. The XML I am parsing may or may not contain a GUID element. If it does not contain an GUID element I want it to return an empty string.

What I tried is:

```
 doc.Elements().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "GUID").Single().Value;
```

where doc is an `XDocument`, but this does not find the value and throws an exception if nothing is found. How can I get the value of the GUID element and make sure no exceptions are thrown if nothing is found?

/edit

```
  var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
            this.RequestId =  (string)doc.Descendants("GUID").SingleOrDefault() ?? 
                     String.Empty;
```

always returns an empty string. Even if there is a GUID.

xmlString looks as follows: `<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><MethodName xmlns:xs=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\><GUID>blabla</GUID></Meth‌odName>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `Descendants` if you want to search over all document. You can cast element to string to get its value without having NullReferenceException if there is no such element in document:

```
var guid = (string)doc.Descendants("GUID").SingleOrDefault() ?? String.Empty;
```

Or

```
var guid = doc.Descendants("GUID")
              .Select(g => (string)g)
              .SingleOrDefault(String.Empty);
```

Or with XPath

```
var guid = (string)doc.XPathSelectElement("//GUID") ?? String.Empty;
```

NOTE: If you have default xml namespace defined in your real xml document, then you should provide namespace to get element name:

```
var ns = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
var guid = (string)doc.Descendants(ns + "GUID").SingleOrDefault() ?? "";
```

Comment: @IlyaIvanov thanks, updated - was interupted in the middle of writing query :(

Comment: This does not capture the GUID but returns an empty string.

Comment: @user2609980 do you have namespace defined in your real xml docuement?

Comment: It looks like this: `<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><MethodName xmlns:xs=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\><GUID>blabla</GUID></MethodName>`.

Comment: @user2609980 I love when in comments it appears, that original data is different with namespaces defined...

Comment: Did not know it was relevant. I'll change the question.

Comment: @user2609980 I updated code to handle default namespace

Comment: Still returns empty string while a GUID is defined unfortunately.

Comment: @user2609980 just verified - returns `blabla` for your sample xml

Comment: You are right it works... I wrote a unit test, but used the input of a different string. Phew! I have slept too long last night. Thanks a lot! (It even works without the namespace.) Thanks!!

Comment: @user2609980 sleeping too long is not that bad as you think :)

Answer (score 2):

If your element is not found it will be returning null. `Single` does not allow null's.

Use `SingleOrDefault` to return a null and then test that null condition...

```
var element = doc.Elements()
    .Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "GUID")
    .SingleOrDefault();

if(element != null) {
    return element.Value;
}
```